# Change Bamboo build repository via REST API

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, bamboo

Is there a way that I can update a Bamboo build's repository via a REST API. I have read their api doc: https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/6.0.3/. But I did not find anything.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Bamboo Specs that was introduced in Bamboo 6.0?

The Bamboo Specs library allows you to define plan configuration as code and send it to Bamboo to have corresponding plans created or updated automatically.

You can read more information about [Bamboo Specs feature here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+Specs). In case you are looking for detailed documentation about specific method or class, you can find it in [Bamboo Specs JavaDocs](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs/latest).

Hope that helps!

Comment: See also [Bamboo Specs Reference Manual](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/latest/) with a lot of code examples.